# Python requests.exceptions.SSLError

Tags: python-3.x

I'm try to write a requests, but get error...
`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)'),))`

code snippet:

```
import requests
    response = requests.head('https://www.google.com')
    print("", response)
```

and i find some solutin,

ex:
pip install cryptography
pip install pyOpenSSL
pip install certifi

or verify=False

but it still not worked.
Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: This works fine with me. You were trying this on google.com? Maybe this is a proxy issue if so

Comment: @BrandonKauffman 
Thank you ! you're right, it proxy issue, i'm using this under one of my django project, when i try to using pure python, it worked.